# Weird Clock in TikTok

Tags: visual

I have seen a photo of a wall clock in TikTok. Can someone explain it? None of the comments there have any idea.[image]

The Malayalam text can be translated as "Those who understood hit duet". There is no clue given.

---

Edit

The question was seen in [this page](https://www.tiktok.com/@user05316687rafikerala/video/6838003797797768449).

Comment: Is this a puzzle? Rot13(Vg ybbxf yvxr na nqiregvfrzrag sbe rvgure FN Ntrapvrf be CX Tnezragf jvgu n cubar ahzore ehaavat ebhaq gur qvny. Bs pbhefr, lbh qba'g arrq gur pybpx ahzoref gb or noyr gb gryy gur gvzr.)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Probably this is the correct explanation. Let us see if there are more probable explanations.

Comment: So it is a puzzle to the extent that you don't know what it is?

Comment: @WeatherVane I have seen this in TikTok. None of the comments there have any idea.

Comment: So it isn't a puzzle within the scope of this site? Please take [the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out more about this site, and also [What topics can I ask about here?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @WeatherVane I posted this with the best of intentions. What do you suggest? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its the mobile telephone number of the shop friend...SA Agencies Manjeri... you can also try....7034394959...two shops...PK Garments...SA Agencies...duet...

Comment: Can you explain how you derived this answer from the image given in the puzzle?

Comment: Thanks. Probably this is the correct explanation. Let us see if there are more probable explanations. I will choose this as the correct answer if nobody comes with better explanation.

Comment: @Rand....I saw the issue this way....there are 12 numbers on a clock face....there is a picture of a phone at 10 o' clock place...this is followed by a zero and ten single digits...so it made me think that it could be a mobile number....so..I rang the number and..hey!....a person answered 'SA agencies'...and in answer to my query replied that his textile shop is located at a place called Manjeri in Kerala,State,India...so